# backbonejs model.toJSON & render

Tags: backbone.js, model, underscore.js, bind, render

I have some model and I want to bind **render** method to it on change. I'm trying to pass the **model.toJSON** to the **render**, but it doesn't work. However it works if I pass model and apply **toJSON** inside **render**.

(the whole code is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/xoeY4hexnqgHnkxap5uj?p=preview)

```
window.onload=function(){

    var defaultModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
          greeting: 'Hello, Dude',
          content: 'Coming soon...'
        }
      }),

      defaultView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'section',
        className: 'default',
        initialize: function(option) {

          this.template = $('#tmpl-default').html();

          this.render();

          var _this = this;

          this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this, this.model.toJSON()));

          $('[name="default-input"]').on('blur', function() {
           console.log('got blurred....');
           _this.model.set('content', this.value);
          });
        },
        render: function(content) {
          if (!content) {
            console.log('%cno content', 'color: green');
            content = this.model.toJSON();
          }
          this.$el.html(_.template(this.template)(content));
          $('#content').html(this.$el);
          return this;
        }
      }),
      viewDefault = new defaultView({
        model: new defaultModel()
      });
};
```

the code above doesn't work. If I change

```
this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this, this.model.toJSON()));
```

to

```
this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this, this.model));
```

and

```
if (!content) {
    content = this.model.toJSON();
}
```

to

```
if (!content) {
    content = this.model.toJSON();
}else{
    content = content.toJSON();
}
```

But why?!

Comment: wondering whether the answer helped...?

Answer (score 0):

A more appropriate way is to use the `listenTo` function on the view, such as:

`this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it doesn't work as you expect is because when you do

```
this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this, this.model.toJSON()));
```

The argument `this.model.toJSON()` passed to render method will always be the initial state of the model at the point when `_.bind` was called.

When you do `content = this.model.toJSON();` inside `render` method, you get the current state, including the expected changes that triggered render.

---

You can better structure your view like this:

```js
defaultView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'section',
  className: 'default',
  initialize: function(option) {
    this.render();
    this.model.on('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
  },
  template: _.template($('#tmpl-default').html()),
  events: {
    'blur [name="default-input"]': 'eventHandler'
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    $('#content').html(this.$el);
    return this;
  },
  eventHandler: function(event) {
    var val = $(event.currentTarget).val();
    this.model.set('content', val);
  }
});
```

Also, look into `listenTo` than `on` like @Jayem suggested to aviod unexpected memory leak issues